# unable to realize why the javascript function is not able to set a variable properly

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to Javascript so bear with me as I try to work through this. I'm trying to maintain a sizig of a DialogoWindow in the application.

What happens is, i have a list of web forms in an array that looks like this...

```
 var formOneList =
        ['Choice', 'Asses'];
```

This is a much abbreviated version, there's actually about 50 items...

Then i basically try to set the size of a dialogWindow based on the `formOneList` name like this...

```
var j = -1;
for (var i = 0, length = formOneList.length; i < length; i++) {
     if (formOneList[i] === formname) {
         j = i;
       }
     }
     if (j > -1) {
        dialogWindow.set_width("500px");
     }
     else
        dialogWindow.set_width("300px");
        dialogWindow.set_height("200px");
```

So basically what I'm wanting for this to do, is if it finds one of the formsOnelist in which case is '`Asses'` - I want it to set the width to `300px`. For some reason, it never sets `J = 1`, instead it loops through all the forms and then goes right into the `ELSE` of next If statement since `J = -1`

I added an alert here...

```
alert(j);
if (j>-1) {....
```

And the alert shows the number that is the order of ASSES in the array which is great than -1 yet it still his the `dialogWindow.set_width("500px")`;

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What's 'formname' and where is it being set?

Comment: @zsawaf = formName is being set on button_click when this form loads. the formName is set correctly, because at the end of the for loop, j is set to item 2, because Asses is 2nd item in Array, i checked because alert(j) right before the if statement, clearly shows that j = 2.

Comment: aren't you missing `{` in the else branch? Wouldn't the second index be 1 (as an array starts with 0) the code shown is well, improvable

Comment: you wrote `if (j > -1) { dialogWindow.set_width("500px"); ...` so, when formname matches, it sets width to 500px, not 300px ... did I get something wrong?

Comment: Could it be to do with the literal comparison `===`? Is formname the same type as formOneList[i]? Try using `==` just to check, though that's often a bad idea...

Comment: @Icepickle - i didn't include the whole function, the formatting is fine

Comment: You described this behaviour: "And the alert shows the number that is the order of ASSES in the array which is great than -1 yet it still his the dialogWindow.set_width("500px");" - but that's correct. j is grater than -1 so the dialog should be 500px no?

Comment: @Matus - i'm an idiot

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time fellas

Comment: Hey it's Monday, I get it :)... but you should close this question now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `if (j > -1)` to `if (j < 0)`. It would behave correctly then.